# Adding +1 day to jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a jQuery datepicker working, outputting to an altField in TIMESTAMP format. I'd like to add +1 day to the altField in order to encompass the day selected (but not show the +1 in the UI). I can't figure out how to implement this. My code looks like this:

```
$('#end_date').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    altField: 'input[name="event_start_date_max"]',
    altFormat: '@',
    onSelect : function(dateText, inst) {
        var epoch = $.datepicker.formatDate('@', $(this).datepicker('getDate')) / 1000;
        $('input[name="event_start_date_max"]').val(epoch);
    }
});
```

If anyone can help out I'd appreciate it.

Comment: you could do something like that i suppose: `epoch + 24*60*60`

Comment: hiya do you want this start date and then in end date + 1 ? http://jsfiddle.net/2qzjg/ let me know I will set it as answer if this is what you want! B-)

Comment: Andy - thanks, it works! Tats_innit - thanks for your offer, problem already solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fiddled a solution **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/3jpUE/)** for you. Basically you can add 86400 or (60*60*24), as I did here below:

```
$('#end_date').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    altField: 'input[name="event_start_date_max"]',
    altFormat: '@',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var epoch = ($.datepicker.formatDate('@', $(this).datepicker('getDate')) / 1000) + (60 * 60 * 24);
        $('input[name="event_start_date_max"]').val(epoch);
    }
});​
```

Comment: It is better to post the solution in the answer and append a link to demo.